# Equality for heat distribution in cup

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am given a temperature function $T(t,x)$ defined on $\Omega$, and an area $\Gamma \subset \partial \Omega$ (part of the boundary of $\Omega$) where heat can get out of the cup.

I know the following details:

- $\partial_t T = \Delta T$ in $(0,\infty) \times \Omega$
- $T = 0$ on $[0,\infty)\times \Gamma$
- $\nabla T \cdot n = 0$ on $[0,\infty) \times \partial \Omega \backslash\Gamma $
- $T = T_0$ on $0\times \Omega$.

I now want to show that

$$
\int_{\Omega} T(t,x)^2 dx = \int_{\Omega} T_0(x)^2 dx - 2 \int_0^t\int_{\Omega} |\nabla T(s,x)|^2dxds.
$$

**I don't know how, and I was given a vague hint: Multiply one of the four given identities (boundary conditions) by something and then integrate over $\Omega$, but I don't know what to multiply by.**

**Similar questions did this multiplying "trick" and then used integration by parts.**

I thought about the following, but it doesn't lead anywhere I think:

$$\int_{\Omega} T(t,x) (T(t,x) - T_0(x)) = \int_{\Omega} T(t,x) \int_0^t \partial_t T(s,x)dsdx \\= \int_{\Omega} \int_0^t (\nabla\cdot\nabla T(s,x))\cdot T(t,x) ds dx
\\=
\int_{\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma} \int_0^t \nabla T(s,x)\cdot T(t,x)\cdot n ds ds_x \\+ \int_{\Gamma} \int_0^t \nabla T(s,x)\cdot T(t,x)\cdot n ds ds_x,$$
which would be equal to zero, since $T$ is zero on $\Gamma$ and $\nabla T \cdot n$ is zero on $\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma$.

I think the minus two might be coming from the identity:

$$
(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2,$$

but I don't see how.

Here are some things that I did figure out:

$$ \int_{\Omega} T(t,x) dx = \int_{\Omega} T_0(x) dx,\quad \text{ for all } t>0
$$

$$T(t,x) = T_0(x) + \int_0^t \partial_t T(s,x)ds$$

$$ T(t,x) - T_0(x) = \int_0^t \partial_t T(s,x)ds =\int_0^t \Delta T(s,x)ds$$

Comment: I'll outline the procedure for you. First, multiply the PDE by $T$ $$T \partial_{t} T=T \Delta T$$ then use that $T \partial_{t} T=\partial_{t} T^{2}/2$ $$\frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} T^{2} = T \Delta T$$ Now integrate over space and time  \begin{align} \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} (T^{2}) dx ds &= \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\Omega} T \Delta T dx ds \end{align} and use the fundamental theorem of calculus on the LHS, integration by parts on the RHS. Finally, use the boundary conditions to show that the evaluated term from integration by parts, $T \nabla T$, is zero.

Comment: @mattos For definite integrals I understand the evaluation part of integration by parts. But for volume integrals  I don't really understand. It seems like I have to use the divergence theorem and integration by parts at the same time:

The evaluated term $T\nabla T$ must be evaluated over $\partial \Omega$? Other questions then also add a normal vector like in the divergence theorem, but I don't understand how integration by parts leads to that:

$$\int_0^t \int_{\partial \Omega} T \cdot \nabla T \cdot n ds_x ds$$.

I do understand why that would be zero.

Comment: @mattos Beside that, your comment would be accepted as a full blown answer. If you want to pursue that, maybe add why you thought of multiplying by $T$, is that something you usually do?

Comment: Note that the divergence theorem _is_ integration by parts, just when the dimension is greater than 1. Use the first corollary [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries) to do the computation, see if you can identify what $\boldsymbol{F}$ and $g$ in the corollary are in your problem. I try not to give answers in general, so that OPs can work through the problem themselves. And yes, multiplying by $T$ is a very standard thing to do. This comes from a knowledge of [minimising functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).